# C# Enum pointing to another Enum (refactoring)

Tags: c#, refactoring, enums

Is there a way I could point an Enum to another Enum? Here are the needs and details:

Currently:

- I have a two public classes com.abcd.MyManager and com.abcd.data.MyObject.
- MyObject class have pretty much everything is private except Types enum member.
- MyManager class uses MyObject class
- Notice MyObject class lives in a separate namespace.
- One of the MyManager methods have following signature:

  `public void Init(string name, MyObject.Types type)

  {

  // does Init

  }`

Refactor requirement:

- Just because of MyObject.Types used in the Init method and also it is living in another namespace. Developers have to include both namespaces in their code. I like to move the MyObject.Types enum to MyManager class. something similar like this:

  `public void Init(string name, MyManager.Types type)

  {

  // does Init

  }`

Any suggestions on how could I do this without breaking current structure? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is how could the developer to use MyManager's Init without using MyObject's namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have one `enum` use the values from another, but you can't make them interchangeable (without casting).

```
public class MyManager
{
    public enum Types
    { 
        Type1 = com.abcd.data.MyObject.Types.Type1,
        Type2 = com.abcd.data.MyObject.Types.Type2,
        Type3 = com.abcd.data.MyObject.Types.Type3
    }
}
```

This will let you cast in between the two `enum`s and get the same value for the same member names, but you'll still have to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why moving the enumeration would break anything. You should be able to just move the enum to `com.abcd.Types`, and make sure the `MyObject` code file includes a using directive for the `com.abcd` namespace. If you really want to have the enum inside `MyManager`, then `MyObject` must refer to `MyManager.Types` instead of just `Types`.

Are there any specific problems you're running into when you attempt the refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

1) Move the MyObject.Types enum to a separate project that both MyObject and MyManager has a reference to.

2)Create an enum in the MyManager project that matches the enum in the MyObject project. Then you can have some kind of mapping method:

```
public void Init(string name, MyManager.Types type)
{
   MyObject.Types t = type.ToMyObjectType();
}

internal static class Extensions
{
   public static MyObject.Types ToMyObjectType(this MyManager.Types t)
   {
      //do mapping
   }
}
```

I wouldn't suggest using the second approach, because if the enum in MyObject ever changes, you need to remember to update this code as well.